# How to call your own ASP.NET MVC project preaent on same machine from xamrin webview

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, webview

I am creating a **Xamarin WebView** for an **ASP.NET MVC5** Application, but when I run the emulator I faced the following: `ERR_Connection Refused`. Can you explain me how to call project present in same machine from Xamarin WebView?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) 
{
  base.OnCreate(bundle);

  // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

  web_view = FindViewById < WebView > (Resource.Id.webview);
  web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
  web_view.LoadUrl("http://localhost:53183/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Localhost within the emulator will be the emulator itself, not your PC.

Change `http://localhost:53183` to:

```
http://:yourpcipaddress53183
```

Note: Most emulators also map "10.0.2.2" and/or "10.0.3.2" as your PC's loopback adapter.

```
http://:10.0.2.2:53183
http://:10.0.3.2:53183
```

You can test it via `adb`:

```
adb shell ping 10.0.2.2
```

Comment: i am getting  blank page after replacing

Comment: Can you use the Android browser and open your web page?

Comment: i again faced blank page in android browser when i open my project but http://www.google.com working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your localhost is running under IIS express, you need to tell your windows machine to accept connections to that site/port. Open PowerShell as administrator:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://{windows-local-ip}:53183/ user=everyone
```

> If your machine language is not english you´ll have to change "everyone" with the corresponding translation.

Then open the file `applicationhost.config` that you can find on `YourSolution/.vs/config/applicationhost.config` and search the site node corresponding to your application:

```
<site name="YourApplication" id="1">...</site>
```

Inside, you´ll find a default `<binding>` node pointing to localhost. Leave it as is, but add a new one with your computer local ip:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindinginformation="*:53183:{local-ip}"></binding>
```

For instance:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindinginformation="*:80:192.168.0.57"></binding>
```

When you launch/debug your website, right click the IIS express icon. You should see something like this (localhost + your ip:port):

[image]

> If you still don´t see your ip like in the picture, restart Visual Studio.

Last, you may need to open the port 53183 in your firewall. Just to make sure it isn´t the firewall blocking the connection, deactivate it and try again.