# Debug Xamarin Sports Sample Locally

Tags: android, azure, xamarin

I am having trouble debugging the Xamarin Sports Sample locally on my development machine, so I can debug both the mobile app and the services on the same machine.

I have got the solutions open in Visual Studio 2015. I created my Google API Credentials and updated the settings with that info. I set the Azure domain to my local IP address (also tried localhost and a fake domain name). I added the authorized javascript origins and redirect URI's into the Google interface with the various combinations of IP, localhost and fake domain name.

It looks like the redirect URI cannot be an IP address. I have tried putting the fake domain name into my hosts file. I can run the services solution and it displays in the browser properly. I can hit `/login/google` in the browser and it looks like it works.

When I run the mobile solution in the emulator and click the login button, I get errors. During my troubleshooting, I have seen various errors, like name not resolved and a few others. I suspected that I could modify the device emulators hosts file to include the fake domain name, but I am not able to get the file system to be read-write, even after trying adb remount. That command says it was successful, but the adb push tells me the file is read-only.

I am using a Nexus 6 API 23 virtual device, if that matters.

Has anyone managed to get this sample to debug both mobile and services locally? Any suggestions on how I can modify the hosts file to see if that works? Any other thoughts on getting this to all run locally?

I have not tried running the iOS project, yet. Will that run into the same challenges?

Answer (score 0):

Your device/emulator probably doesnt´t have access to your server machine.
Check your server local host ip, and run this with PowerShell as administrator:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.X.X:XXXX/ user=everyone
```

Replace the ip:port with your host ip and the app port.
Then create a new `<Binding>` in your `applicationhost.config` pointing to the above ip:port.

More details (and possible duplicate) here: 
[How to call your own ASP.NET MVC project preaent on same machine from xamrin webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772966/how-to-call-your-own-asp-net-mvc-project-preaent-on-same-machine-from-xamrin-web/37780946#37780946)