# How to connect other system to my localhost port in signal R

Tags: wpf, signalr

I have tried using **localhost** in my wpf application it works only for local .. i need to create a hub server where other system should be connected in this server..i have tried allowing the port in **inbound** and **outbound** rules in firewall which is mentioned in stackoverflow..

my two systems where connection in same network domain.. when i tried giving my **ip address** in creating hub server .. it throws exception..

Please help me on this..

Comment: Are you using IIS Express from Visual Studio to run your application? If that´s the case, check the answer in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795630/debug-xamarin-sports-sample-locally/37795801#37795801

Comment: i am not using IIS Express .. since i need to run my application with ip address... i have referred the link which you provided.. there is no seperate server.. my local ip itself should be used as server link to connect users.. so that the users from other system will be able to connect to my local ip

Comment: Well, I would try to disable the firewall to make sure you configured it well. Then I would try to run `netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.X.X:XXXX/ user=everyone` in your server machine. That command tells your machine to accept connections from other machines